# User Authentication with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am very new to WordPress; I usually build my sites and web apps using HTML, JQuery, and PHP. This WordPress thing has thrown me for a loop. A little background: Another company has created a new website for us and they created it as a WordPress site. I have the files and WordPress database which is all installed on our servers.

I need to build a user authentication page for users to use to login and view another page. So how do I implement user authentication with WordPress, but not give users access to the WordPress administration, and have the page for the users ensure they're logged in? All of this needs to remain with the overall theme of the WordPress website.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when creating WordPress user, you can decide their administration level there.

You can really rein-in your users using this plugin - http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager.

Now, if i'm not mis-interpreting what you're saying, you want to serve different content to certain users. Well, my friend. Fear not, that's where plugins are handy.

**1.**

http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-specific-content/ (select specific users by user name, or by role name who can view a specific post content or page content)

**2.**

http://wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/ (restrict all, none, or certain pages/posts to logged in users only)

If you're unsure how to install, activate, or use the plugin. There are an abundance of youtube & written tutorials for you to utilize. P.S. Don't neglect the wordpress documentation, it's often very informative.